# asp GridView add data to a certain column (after TemplateField) with Boundfield?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a asp:GridView wich in code behind is asigned to a List with Objects.

```
gwMyGridview.DataSource = test; // test is a list with some objects (two fields)
gwTract.DataBind();
```

I can add buttons and stuff to the columns, but my data (two columns) are always the last two columns. I know BoundField can be used, but I still get two columns in the end.
How can i do this: column1 = data1, column2 = button, column3 = data. 
Now it looks like this: button, data, data

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't let the GridView to auto generate the columns. To do this, follow these steps:

1- Click on the GridView's Tasks (little arrow on top of the GridView when you click on it) and click on Edit Columns, and uncheck the "Auto-Generate fields" field, or from the Markup set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false`

2 - Add your columns manually to the GridView, by either adding them in the previous dialog (Fields) or in the markup, in the exact order you want them to a appear in your GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="data1" HeaderText="Data1" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CustomColumn"></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="data2" HeaderText="Data2" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

After that you can bind normally.

Comment: Nice! Hold on I will try this!

Comment: YES! Thank you, it worked perfectly. AutoGenerateColums="False" did it!

Comment: It really helped! :) Now I just need to find out how to read if a radio button inside the GridView is selected... :)

Comment: Post another question with this, share the link and specify if you want to know the value within asp.net or javascript ;), but of course, make sure there is not asked previously first :p

Comment: I could not find a similar question, so here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109330/asp-read-value-from-radiobuttonlist-inside-of-a-gridview