# ASP Read value from RadioButtonList inside of a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a ASP.NET GridView which I fill with data, one button, and one RadioButtonList with 4 radio buttons. How can I get which radio button is selected by pressing a button outside of the GridView (using c# codebehind)?
The button inside the GridView shall be used for removing a row (RowCommand event I think...)

Code from within the GridView:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="value" HeaderText="Value" />
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false" HeaderText="Foo?">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="true">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false" HeaderText="">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Remove" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Comment: Can we get some code snippets from `RowCommand` event

Comment: Let's see the GridView's code as well (markup, and code behind)

Comment: You need to post the code.

Comment: @HanletEscaño The code behind isn't written yet. I don't know how to extract the value from the RadioButtonList :)

Comment: @Half_Baked That code you posted is good :)

Comment: how many rows in grid view and u want all row or specific row radiobutton list

Comment: @HanletEscaño Yes it works, but how can I read wich radio button is selected?

Comment: @AmitSingh It's dynamic. Between 1-10 rows in gridview. I have radiobuttonlist on each row.

Comment: @The-Val onRowCommand code is not written.. I don't know how to read the radio button value

Comment: WHEN U WANT THE SELECTED rADIO BUTTON THE BUTTON OUTSIDE GRIDVIEW OR BUTTON INSIDE GRIDVIEW

Comment: @AmitSingh outside gridview. The one inside is for removing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know which RadioButton was selected follow these steps from your current code:

Modify your button to this:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false" HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Remove" CommandArgument="<%#  ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex%>"
            CommandName="remove" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

so now you have `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` properties filled in. The `CommandArgument` will pass the index of the row to your `RowCommand` event.

Then your `RowCommand` event looks like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "remove")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        if (index >= 0)
        { 
            //index is the row, now obtain the RadioButtonList1 in this row
            RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
            if (rbl != null)
            {
                string selected = rbl.SelectedItem.Text;
                Response.Write("Row " + index + " was selected, radio button " + selected);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: I would recommend adding `Value` to your `RadioButtons` so that you check against values and not text.

Comment: Wow! I will test this. I'm not sure if I understand how this works...CommandArgument="<%#  ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex%>". I'll look into it :)

Comment: @Half_Baked, the way it works is that everytime you click on a "Remove" button, the buttons will cause a post, and the RowCommand event will be triggered. With the CommandArgument you can pass any value to the RowCommandEvent. With this value I know which row is selected, and with this I can easily find the RadioButtonList.

Comment: Thanks. Very good explained. How is it with the databind? Do I need to  do it after a remove?

Comment: Yes, you re-bind your GridView after you remove the item from the DataSource.

Comment: Thanks! This was a huge help! :)